# ldap_search will not accept filter with parentheses in the search input

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

In a php page I'm working on, an LDAP connection is established from which a list of cn entries are pulled and put into a dropdown. The selection from the dropdown is sent via form submission to another php scrips which checks the selected cn against the LDAP to grab more associated information.

For most names this is no problem; however, a cn was recently added that includes parentheses enclosing a nickname, and when that name is selected it causes the ldap_search() method to return false. Below is the code, where $employeename is the sanitized employee name.

```
...

$dn = "cn=users,dc=our-domain,dc=com";
$filter = "(cn=".$employeename.")";

$attrs = array("cn", "mail");
$rslt = ldap_search($ldapsvr, $dn, $filter, $attrs);

$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapsvr, $rslt);

...
```

The $filter string ends up as

```
(cn=First (FN) Last)
```

where First is the first name, Last is the last name, and FN is the included nickname. I have tried escaping the parentheses as \28 and \29 (as provided [here](http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm), where it also says matched parentheses do not need to be escaped), but it did not help. Names that work include letters, spaced, and periods (for middle initials).

```
(cn=First \28FN\29 Last)
```

EDIT: ldap_search is returning false, not dying. One of the lines I included while investigating would fail and die if $rslt was false and not an array.

EDIT: I escaped the inner parentheses only,. as the outer never gave any trouble

Comment: What kind of error occurs without adding the escaped characters?

Comment: With unescaped characters, ldap_search() returns false. I think confused myself while writing the question; while testing, print_r($rslt) would cause the script to die when the search returned false. I'll fix the the question. Sorry about that

Comment: Have you tried tailing the LDAP server log to see what it says about the query coming across from PHP?

Comment: Do you set your ldap options for `PROTOCOL_VERSION` 3?

Comment: @sixeightzero the script currently does not set any options; I'll trysetting the protocol to three (using the first example here http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php)

Comment: @quickshiftin I don't think I have access to it, but if the problem persists I'll try to get someone to look for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add an operand as a sort of order-of-operations. I had a similar issue on the `title` field until I did similar to the following.

```
$filter = "(&(cn=$employeename))";
```

On some systems, you need to escape `()` with a `\`.

```
$filter = "(&(cn=James \(Jim\) Doe))";
```

Hang tight, working on a escape function.

Comment: I swapped in the filter you provided, but the ldap_search() call is still returning false (I corrected the error result in the question). Would the php version make a difference as far as the functionality of the method?

Comment: What version are you using? This worked on 5.3.8 and 5.4.4. I also declared `LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION` to 3

Comment: Setting the protocol version to 3 didn't affect the search return. As far as php version, we seem to be using 5.3.3

Comment: I think I've tried escaping them like that, but I'll try it again on Monday.

Comment: Ok let me know. This worked for me when i tried it yestsrday.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses must be escaped in search filter assertion values. See also: [rfc4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515) (section 4).

Comment: I've already tried replacing the inner open and close parentheses with \28 and \29, respectively. I'll update the question to reflect that I only replaced the inner ones; should I try replacing both sets?

Comment: No only the inner ones if you do. Outter ones need to be standard as they are part of the meta of the query

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "assertion values".